# Heroku: Allow use of third-party analytics services?

Tags: heroku, settings, account

Under my [Heroku Account settings](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account), should I uncheck "Allow use of third-party analytics services"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

[This is where](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/247) they announce the possibility to opt out. "Privacy policy" redirects to Salesforce (the parent company of Heroku) policy. It's not crystal clear what they are meaning, so I opted out.